# Token pasting in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, c99, variadic-macros, stringification

After reading about [**VA_NARG**](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c/browse_frm/thread/77ee8c8f92e4a3fb)

I tried to implement function overloading depending on number of arguments in **C** using macros.
Now the problem is:

```
void hello1(char *s) { ... }
void hello2(char *s, char *t) { ... }
// PP_NARG(...)           macro returns number of arguments :ref to link above
 // does not work
#define hello(...)         hello ## PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__)  

int main(void)
{
   hello("hi");   // call hello1("hi");
   hello("foo","bar"); // call hello2("foo","bar");
   return 0;
}
```

I've read [this](http://c-faq.com/ansi/stringize.html) from C-faq. But still could not get it to work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of the evaluation rules for macros. You would have to define some sort of helper macro that receives the number as a token:

```
#define HELLO_1(N, ...)         hello ## N
#define HELLO_0(N, ...)         HELLO_1(N, __VARGS__)
#define HELLO(...)         HELLO_0(PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__), __VARGS__)
```

or so. You could also have a glance into the prerelease of the documentation of [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__default__arguments.html). This will provide you more comfortable macro tools to do that directly.

Comment: "or so" indeed.  It needs one more level of indirection to make it work.

Comment: @John: yeah, thanks. I always use my own version of a paste macro for that, so I have a hard time to remember how much levels of indirection you need if you just have `##`. I adapted my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks that works. but HELLO("foo") give hello1; not hello1("foo"). But i get the idea...

Answer (score 4):

That `PP_NARG` is a rather impressive piece of craziness!

Following the `glue` example in the C99 standard (6.10.3.5, example 4), the following produces the desired results:

```
#define glue(a, b)   a ## b
#define xglue(a, b)  glue(a, b)

#define hello(...)   xglue(hello, PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__))(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a C99 compiler available to check, but this should work:

```
#define helloN(N, ...) hello ## N (__VA_ARGS__)
#define hello(...) helloN(PP_NARG(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__)
```