# Count number of parameters in C variable argument method call

Tags: c, gcc, variadic-functions

When using va_start(), va_arg() and va_end() to read parameters passed to a method, is there a way to count how many arguments there are?

According to the man page if you call va_arg() too many times you get "random errors":

> If there is no next argument, or if
>   type is not compatible with the type
>   of the actual next argument (as
>   promoted according to the default
>   argument promotions), random errors will occur.

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c/browse_frm/thread/77ee8c8f92e4a3fb

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.  a Variable Argument function (such as `printf`), must "know" when to stop looking for more arguments.

`printf` knows by the number of `%d`, `%s` and other symbols in its format string.

Other functions sometimes use Sentinel values:

```
sumValues(1, 3, 5, 7, 6, 9, -1); // will add numbers until it encounters a -1
```

Other functions may have the number of parameters stated up front:

```
AddNames(4, "Bill", "Alice", "Mike", "Tom");
```

Answer (score 9):

Here is a fairly astonishing trick that allows you to build what you want using C99's variadic macros:

> [PP_NARG()](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.std.c/browse_frm/thread/77ee8c8f92e4a3fb)
>   Returns the number of arguments contained in `__VA_ARGS__`

You can use this to write a macro wrapping your real function that adds a count to the front of the real function's arguments.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769381/token-pasting-in-c).  However probably the classical approaches are still more sensible for a year or three yet!

---

The code, so that this answer is useful even without the Usenet archive...

```
/* The PP_NARG macro returns the number of arguments that have been
  * passed to it.
  */

#define PP_NARG(...) \
         PP_NARG_(__VA_ARGS__,PP_RSEQ_N())
#define PP_NARG_(...) \
         PP_ARG_N(__VA_ARGS__)
#define PP_ARG_N( \
          _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8, _9,_10, \
         _11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20, \
         _21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30, \
         _31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40, \
         _41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50, \
         _51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60, \
         _61,_62,_63,N,...) N
#define PP_RSEQ_N() \
         63,62,61,60,                   \
         59,58,57,56,55,54,53,52,51,50, \
         49,48,47,46,45,44,43,42,41,40, \
         39,38,37,36,35,34,33,32,31,30, \
         29,28,27,26,25,24,23,22,21,20, \
         19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11,10, \
         9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0
```

Comment: I should say this is lovely :-) Nice finding!

Comment: Exactly what I'm going to say!

Comment: P99 will have a set of macros inspired by that and which could be exactly what you need. Unfortunately the release will only be in some week time, but if you want to have a look in the documentation: http://p99.gforge.inria.fr/p99-html/group__variadic.html

Comment: @Jens: at a glance, the P99 documentation looks interesting and all, but I rather lost interest in reading further when I got to this bit: "This file is part of the P99 project. You received this file as as part of a confidential agreement and you may generally not redistribute it and/or modify it, unless under the terms as given in the file LICENSE."  There was no confidential agreement, there is no LICENSE file to be found on the documentation website, and I am generally uninterested in things I cannot tinker with.

Comment: @John: I agree completely. This license will change and is actually the reason why the P99 is not yet released: I am in discussion with my hierarchy of which license to choose. Probably it will be something like LGPL. But procedures are slow, here in France.

Comment: @Jens: Fair enough, that discussion is hardly ever fun.  Complaint withdrawn :-)

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to know how many arguments were passed.  First, you can have one of the function parameters tell you (like `printf` for example).  The other way is to have a sentinel value at the end of your list - for instance, you could stop at a `NULL` argument.

You can use `va_copy` if you choose the second method, but still want to count the parameters before deciding what to do with them.

Answer (score 2):

A handy variation to the sentinel version of variadic functions is to define a macro that automagically adds up the expected sentinel as last argument :

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <assert.h>

int sum_(int unused, ...)
{
  va_list args;
  int sum, val;

  va_start(args, unused);
  
  sum = 0;
  while ((val = va_arg(args, int)) != -1)
    sum += val;

  va_end(args);

  return sum;
}

#define sum(...) sum_(41, ##__VA_ARGS__, -1)

void main(void)
{
  assert(sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6) == 21);
}
```

Comment: 41 should be 42 :)

Comment: Was at first, then I edited it to 41 because 'Sum41' was too tempting ;-)