# How do I identify the last variable argument?

Tags: c++, char, arguments, printf, variadic-functions

So in my function I want to take a variable number of char pointers.

```
void myFunction(char *_Name, ...);
```

Only, when I iterate through the arguments my code breaks because I'm not sure how to stop on the last argument I pass and not keep going.

```
void myClass::myFunction(char *_Name, ...)
{    
    char *a;
    std::vector<char*> names;
    va_list VariablePathList;
    va_start (VariablePathList, _Name);

    a = _Name;

    bool exitLoop = false;
    while(!exitLoop)
    {
        names.emplace_back(a);
        a = va_arg(VariablePathList, char *);

        //what must I do to set "exitLoop = true" at the right time?
    }

    va_end (VariablePathList);
}
```

Say I pass two char pointers into myFunction, then the code breaks on the third loop when va_arg is calling on unreadable memory.

Without telling myFunction how many agruments I have given it how can it find out the number to set exitLoop before the code breaks?

I can not seem to find straight forward information on how printf() and the like do this, so there could lie the solution I'm after.

Really, thank you in advance.

Comment: This is well explained on [the Wikipedia article about _varargs_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Example_in_C); was something about the article not clear?

Comment: ...and the subject of *numerous* related questions on this site, [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868289/count-number-of-parameters-in-c-variable-argument-method-call).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`printf` does it by parsing the format string. Some other functions do it by accepting an explicit `count` argument before the varargs. Which way to go will depend on your specific needs.

Really, though, it's 2015 now so you should be using variadic templates rather than archaic C customs. I also definitely do not advise storing `char*` in containers.

Here is *all* you need:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

template <typename... T>
void foo(T... args)
{    
    std::vector<std::string> names{args...};
    // now use `names`
}
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e1237f966eb03722))